# Persisting type in Java - should I be using flags?

Tags: object-oriented, data, maintainability, persistence

Is there some specific piece of advice around persist values that indicate type? Specifically I want to know if I should persist a flag/state indicating the type in persistence or not. I get the feeling I'm forgetting/not understanding some core concept of OO or data modelling.

Something that's been on my mind for the last while is to consider when to use flags and when not to, and intermixing this idea of recreating objects of some certain type out of persistence.

The reason for my concern over flags is that in the software I often create (in-house created corporate software developed with Java), these flags become pieces of information which are hard to maintain and which subsequent developers need to be aware of in order to maintain them (perhaps creating code bloat).

So, when I persist my `foo`, should I persist with it some flag that indicates whether it is a `foobar` or a `foobo`? Is there specific advice about this, some gap in my OO-foo or data modelling that I'm forgetting?

Comment: I would look at Java's built-in serialization for an example. What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you persist and what you persist. It would make sense to use some enums when wanting to persist a class hierarchy and you want to persist all the elements of the class hierarchy in a single place.

Take for example mapping inheritance to a single table in and ORM (e.g. `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` in JPA). Say you have a superclass `User` and two subclasses `CustomerUser` and AdminUsers and you want them mapped to a single column `users`. Here you need a discriminator column to differentiate between possible user types; this column is better a string or an enum rather than a flag. This column should have the value `customer` for entries that represent `CustomerUser` and `admin` for entries that represent `AdminUser`.

But if you do not have some common elements from distinct classes that have a common superclass, then it doesn't make sense to specify the type when you persist it. You should know from the context/metadata what the type is (be it a column name in a relational database, a name of the file, a tag name in a XML etc.) and you shouldn't strongly couple it with your application model because you may want other applications reading the persisted data. Given the above example you might as well have two distinct columns `admin_users` and `customer_users` and then there is no need for persisting the type.